# Is it possible to create a new local git repository without cloning (and therefore without push and pull?

Tags: git

I have looked at this [this link](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/creating-local-git-repositories-yeah-its-that-simple/) and it suggests a way to create a local git repository and then clone it and use it.

Out of curiosity, is it possible to skip the cloning and somehow init and use a local git repository directly? That is, have a situation where you would do `git commit` to commit changes, but never need to invoke `git push` because there IS no backing "remote" repository.

Naturally, this would be for single-person source control only, rather than collaborations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run

```
git init
```

in a directory you want to use as a repository.

Comment: Yeah, just to add to this. Normally you would run, `git init`, followed by `git add .` (if you want to add all the files in that directory), and then a `git commit -am "Initial commit."`. Then you would have a working setup from the current directory.